# SQL Server trigger to Insert, Update, Delete data into another table based on changes in another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I am extremely new to SQL Server (Express) and would very much appreciate anyone willing to help a newbie. I have a split Access database that I have migrated the tables into SQL Server. The last issue I need to resolve is to create a trigger that will update data rows in one table based on data updates/changes in another table. There are two tables I need to create triggers on, but I'm assuming once I get one right, I just need to use the same logic for the second one.

The gist of it is that data is entered in `tblData` and `tblFamily` and certain columns in those tables are the same as some columns in `Contacts` (for example, Name, Address, City, State, Zip...etc).

As new data is entered in one or both of the two tables, or data is updated in one or both of the two tables, or data is deleted in one or both of the two tables --- I need for that data to be the same in `tblContacts`.

I'm assuming the best way is to do a trigger, but if there's a better way, I'm happy to learn.

So far I've got this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ContactsTrigger 
ON [dbo].[tblData]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, 
                              EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
                              Address, City, StateProvince, ZIPPostal, 
                              id, ContactIDType)
        SELECT
            LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, 
            EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
            Address, City, StateProvince, ZipPostal, 
            ID, ContactIDType
        FROM 
            INSERTED
GO
```

This seems to work for inserting a new record, but when I change data in an existing record in `tblData`, it just inserts a new record in `Contacts` so that I then have a duplicate record of sorts (old value and new value). I  don't need this -- I need for it to UPDATE the record in the `Contacts` table when data is changed from that same record in `tblData`, while at the same time also continuing to insert NEW records or deleting records based on new records entered or old records deleted in `tblData`.

I feel very stupid asking for this as I'm sure it must be an easy solution, but I am very much a novice at this and am willing to look foolish to obtain a little help or direction. =D

Comment: Is there any relationship between tblData and Contacts? In other words, when you update tblData how would you know what record to update in Contacts?

Comment: Hi Alex. I have foreign key ID in Contacts to PK ID tblData.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decide whether to update or insert - based on the values entered. Then, in your trigger, you must have two separate statements - one to insert (as you have already), one to update.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ContactsTrigger 
ON [dbo].[tblData]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF ....... (you need to somehow decide whether to update or insert here) ......
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName,     
                                  EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
                                  Address, City, StateProvince, ZIPPostal, 
                                  id, ContactIDType)
            SELECT
                LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, 
                EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
                Address, City, StateProvince, ZipPostal, 
                ID, ContactIDType
            FROM 
                INSERTED
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Contacts
        SET LastName = i.LastName, FirstName = i.FirstName, 
            MiddleName = i.MiddleName, EmailAddress = i.EMailAddress, 
            HomePhone = i.HomePhone, MobilePhone = i.MobilePhone, 
            Address = i.Address, City = i.City, 
            StateProvince = i.StateProvince, ZipPostal = i.ZipPostal, 
            ContactIDType = i.ContactIDType
        FROM
            Inserted i            
        WHERE 
            -- define some condition that links the rows in the `Inserted` pseudo table 
            -- with the `Contacts` table - I just **guessed** it might be the `ID` column
            ID = I.ID  


    END
GO
```

So for now, your job is to figure out what kind of condition you could test on to know whether a row is new and should be inserted, or updated.

- Could it be the fact that the `ID` value already exists in `Contacts`?
- Could it be the combination of first and last name? Other columns?

**UPDATE:** if your column `ID` is the deciding factor - try this: it first updates all those rows in `dbo.Contacts` that are already in the table, then it inserts those that aren't part of `dbo.Contacts`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ContactsTrigger 
ON [dbo].[tblData]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- first update existing rows in dbo.Contacts with values from "Inserted"...
    UPDATE dbo.Contacts
    SET LastName = i.LastName, FirstName = i.FirstName, 
        MiddleName = i.MiddleName, EmailAddress = i.EMailAddress, 
        HomePhone = i.HomePhone, MobilePhone = i.MobilePhone, 
        Address = i.Address, City = i.City, 
        StateProvince = i.StateProvince, ZipPostal = i.ZipPostal, 
        ContactIDType = i.ContactIDType
    FROM
        Inserted i            
    WHERE 
        -- define some condition that links the rows in the `Inserted` pseudo table 
        -- with the `Contacts` table - I just **guessed** it might be the `ID` column
        ID = I.ID  

    -- then secondly insert new rows into dbo.Contacts 
    INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName,     
                              EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
                              Address, City, StateProvince, ZIPPostal, 
                              id, ContactIDType)
        SELECT
            LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, 
            EmailAddress, HomePhone, MobilePhone, 
            Address, City, StateProvince, ZipPostal, 
            ID, ContactIDType
        FROM 
            INSERTED i
        WHERE
            i.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Contacts);

GO
```

Comment: Thanks Marc - Yes, the ID value will already exist in Contacts. I will try what you have here and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I adapted what you shared but it doesn't like the "Else" for some reason - I used IF NOT EXISTS(Select....) and Insert into Contacts, then ELSE Begin with the rest of what you suggested...And all is good except the Else is flagging incorrect syntax.  What am I missing?  Sorry. I seriously am only a week or two into SQL Server from Access so I'm not exactly sure how to construct this..

Comment: @cheryl: tried to update my response with a snippet of code that first updates existing rows, then inserts those that aren't in the table already

Comment: The new code executed and did update records in Contacts perfectly, but did not insert new data in Contacts. Not sure why...the Where i.ID Not In(Select ID From dbo.Contacts) should have done it I would think.  ...
BTW fwiw I have to allow nulls in the ID since I'm also bringing in data to Contacts from another table which means the ID (tblData) would be null in those instances.

Comment: I took the Where i.ID Not In -- completely out just to see if it would insert without it and it doesn't...

Comment: Got it working! I split your new code into two triggers, one for insert and the other for update, and took out the Where clause on the insert trigger and it works perfectly now.  Thanks for your help!